# Custom popup in Activities slide out

Tags: web8.5, gui-extensions, workflow, sdl-tridion

Is it possible to implement a popup dialog when a content author approves a Bundle Workflow i.e. in Activity dashboard in Tridion, when a content author selects a particular Next Activity in the dropdown, we want to show a popup with a message like “By approving this bundle, I certify that I have obtained all the necessary approvals for the content changes from the requestors .Etc. etc….”. This should happen only on selection of particular next Activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved using a UI extension. In short, you can target the Activity dialogue from JQuery and make manipulate the DOM which opens up for a variety of approaches.

The simplest, imho, would be to initially hide the "Finish Activity" button and display a fake "Finish Activity" button to display a modal dialogue with your approval message. If the users clicks "Yes" you can then display the correct "Finish Activity" button and let them finish their Activity.

Comment: There is no other supported extension point here. Be sure to raise hte point that the code will be manipulating the DOM directly and likely require analysis/update for upgrades.

Comment: Thanks! I did try to write a GUI extension but could not find the command which i can extend on this particular Finish Activity sidebar page. Usually buttons are decorated with something like "c:command" and we can use that name to extend that command but that is not the case here. Am i missing something here?

Comment: @BhushanMali you'll have to use a DOM-inspector to figure out the ID's of the objects you want to manipulate and then hit them using JQuery. Last time I did this I just added my script as generic resource and relied on the ID's to make sure it was only applied on the workflow activity window. SDL.jQuery(".FinishActivityPage") would be a starting point

Comment: Thanks @KarimMaxzoni! Since there is no supported extension point available on this screen, I guess I will go with your suggestion and update my findings.

Comment: We had to modify Tridion js file for FinishActivity to call our custom JS for showing and handling the popup. It is not a recommended approach but the only viable option to achieve what we needed. So thanks for pointing in right direction @KarimMazzoni!

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by catching the on click event and displaying the predefined text (Loaded from CMS).
After the button click continues to the next activity. No manipulation of the DOM involved.